# Xamarin MVVM how to update both model and database on switch toggle?

Tags: database, xamarin, mvvm

In view:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOnStatus}"/>
```

My Timer saving mechanism to the database is using the Repository pattern. This takes care of saving to the database.

```
public ICommand SaveTimerCommand { get; set; }
SaveTimerCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                await this.timerRepository.AddOrUpdateTimer(Timer);
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, "saveoccured");
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            });
```

My Timer class is:

```
public class Timer :INotifyPropertyChanged{
        
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //some other fields...
        private bool isOnStatus { get; set; }
        public bool IsOnStatus
        {
            get { return isOnStatus; }
            set {
                isOnStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            
        }
    }
```

Whenever I click the switch button, the database immediately needs to be updated. But in MVVM, looks like only the Model gets updated.
If I try to invoke Database inside **OnPropertyChanged**, then what happens is, on startup, the code runs through this before even the Timer List View is loaded from the database. How do I know it? I observed that phenomenon through the breakpoints!

So would anyone please suggest me a solution? How can both MVVM data and the database be updated?

Comment: You have the right idea: you need to add the Database access to OnPropertyChanged. All you are missing is an if-check to make sure the Database is ready to be accessed. If it isn't, then don't touch it. If there isn't an obvious test currently, then add `public static bool IsReady;` in some class. Set this `true` after initializing everything your app needs.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I didn't find an obvious check of all Objects being loaded. Also, I tried a later technique: I kept IsReady as a Global variable, set that to false initially, which sets true inside LoadTimers() method which loads Timers List from DB. And then put the check inside OnPropertyChanged. But somehow the leakage happens. And also, accessing the repository through OnPropertyChanged is giving me a null exception inside ```UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate")```

Comment: You'll have to find what is null. Put breakpoint at OnPropertyChanged, and step through the code till you see it. Also, Debug / WIndows / Exception Settings - make sure Common Language Runtime exceptions are checked.